# width of paragraph in multicolumn tables

Tags: tables, tabu, multicolumn

I have problem that I don't know how to solve. Look at `\multicolumn{2}{p{18.5cm}}{bla}` and please tell me how to set paragraph width to fill whole multicolumn space? I discovered this (18.5cm) value experimentally but would be awesome to use some auto-width-setting. Is it possible? Please help me.

```
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {p{5.5cm}X[l,p]}

    a           & aa \\
    b           & bb \\
    c           & cc \\

    \addlinespace[1cm]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{ \textcolor{blue}{ \textit{ \textls[100]{bla} } } } \\   
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{18.5cm}}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla } \\
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: In this case you can use `p{\linewidth}`. Is it working?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The additional space around columns in a table is usually `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=2mm

\begin{center}    
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {p{5.5cm}X[l,p]}

    a           & aa \\
    b           & bb \\
    c           & cc \\

    \addlinespace[1cm]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{bla}}
 \\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla} \\
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\dimexpr` is an e-TeX feature (nowadays LaTeX has enabled e-TeX usually). It allows an expandable calculation and can be used, where TeX expects a length. `\relax` closes the expression and is removed by `\dimexpr`.

If package `calc` is loaded, then the column specifier `p{...}` supports its syntax and you can use:

```
\usepackage{calc}
...
\multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{...}
```